# shell script relative position from the file

Tags: command-line, scripting, macintosh, macos, npm

I have almost no idea about shell scripts or commands in linux

I have a project named `projectx`

`projectX` happens to be in `users/hardik/desktop/projectx`

I have created a shell script `start.sh`. This is the content of shell script

```
echo "Starting typescript build in new terminal.."

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "npm run build"' 

sleep 3

echo "Starting firebase functions...."

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "firebase emulators:start --only functions"'


echo "Process compelete.. Check if there were two terminals window open"
```

now this works but say here

`osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "npm run build"'`

it runs that in the root and hence gives the following error

ENOENT: no such file or directory, open `/Users/hardik/package.json`

How can I make it execute in the path which is relative to `start.sh`

Update: I tried these but it didn't work

```
cd "$(dirname $(readlink -f "$0"))"
echo "Starting typescript build in new terminal.."
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "npm run watch:scss"' 
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "npm run watch"'
echo "Process compelete.. Check if there were two terminals window open"
```

This is what it logs for the above

```
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
usage: dirname path
Starting typescript build in new terminal..
tab 1 of window id 1579
tab 1 of window id 1580
```

also the below snippet doesn't work either

```
cd -P -- "${0%/*}" || exit
echo "Starting typescript build in new terminal.."
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "npm run watch:scss"' 
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "npm run watch"'
echo "Process compelete.. Check if there were two terminals window open"
```

Same error

Comment: Why do you need to npm build in a new Terminal window?

Comment: @glennjackman `npm watch`.  I want one command to start everything. Since both of them are watch, they might also throw error if something goes wrong. for that, I don't want things to happen in the same terminal and I also don't want to run two npm commands whenever I start a project.

Comment: Possibly helpful (but I can't say whether it works on macOS): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50392/315749

Answer (score 1):

You can add
`cd -P -- "${0%/*}" || exit` or `cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" || exit`
to your script to jump into the directory in which the script resides.

`$0` is a [built-in variable](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-special-variables.htm) holding the path of the script as given to the interpreter (will typically be an absolute path if the script was looked up in `$PATH`).

The `${0%/*}` construct uses the shell's built-in [String Manipulation](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) to remove from the end the shortest bit of the variable matching `/*`, which leaves you with just the directory name (would work as long as `$0` contains at least one `/` character which is generally the case).

Comment: `$0` doesn't always contain the full name of the script, it generally contains the name used to invoke the script.

Comment: Right, but if it's in your path, `$0` is set to the full path.  Otherwise you specify either the absolute or relative path, and `cd` will still succeed in putting you into that absolute or relative path.

Comment: But nothing in the OP suggests that his script is in his path.

Comment: @user420417 I tried what you said based on my underdstanding. Didn't work (updated question for the same)

Comment: You may use something as `if [ "$0" = "${0#/*}" ]; then mypath=${PWD}/${0%/*}; else mypath=${0%/*}; fi` to also deal with the `sh script` kind of invocation (that has no slash in "$0"). And (though I don't know whether it's supported on macOS) `readlink -f "$0"` to handle the case of a script invoked as a symbolic link.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether this works under MacOS; it does under Linux:

```
#! /bin/bash
  
arg1="$(awk 'BEGIN { RS="\0" }; NR==2 { print $0 "x"; exit; }' /proc/$$/cmdline; echo x)"
arg1="${arg1%x}"

if [[ $arg1 =~ / ]]; then
    # path contains at least one /
    dir_rel_path="${arg1%/*}"
    cd "$dir_rel_path"
fi

echo "$PWD"
```