# How do I convert a relative to an absolute path, portably and robustly?

Tags: shell, path, portability, bourne-shell

Suppose I'm running bash on a Unix-ish system - not necessarily Linux and not necessarily very new; and it may not have every bit of software I'd like.

Now, I have a relative path for which I want to get the absolute path. What's the most robust and portable way of doing this?

The answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24293/converting-relative-path-to-absolute-path) seem to mostly assume the GNU core utilities are installed, which I would rather not do.

Bonus points if your answer works on any Bourne Shell variant.

Comment: One way to be more portable than using `pwd` and changing dirs(and it's funny that you want a robust way to get absolute paths but didn't said changing dirs were allowed, and also considered this "safer" than install gnu `readlink`) is to make a little utility in `C` using `realpath()` function - https://stackoverflow.com/a/229038/2231796

Comment: @nwildner: A C compiler is definitely not installed on every system you know...

Comment: Maybe you should add this to your answer, that it requires a portable solution that could also range from embedded to powerfull servers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if the environment variable `$PWD` was set in the bourne shell, but the [command `pwd` exists since the old minix](http://www.unix.com/man-page/minix/1/pwd/) and is [part of POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pwd.html), so:

```
abs_path="$(cd "$rel_path" && pwd -P)"
```

Comment: +1 for the first suggestion, but the second suggestion is the opposite of what I need, i.e. something I can really not bank on.

Comment: Fair point @einpoklum , readlink removed.

Answer (score 0):

What I do now is

```
absolute_path="$(cd "$relative_path"; echo "$PWD")"
```

I wonder if Bourne Shell had `$PWD` though.

Comment: `PWD` is in POSIX at least. To avoid the `echo`, you may use `pwd -P`: `abs_path="$( cd "$rel_path" && pwd -P )"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Cwd` core module from Perl. This module provides functions for determining the pathname of the current working directory.

```
perl -MCwd -le 'print Cwd::realpath("foo")'
```

Perl is generally already installed on Linux and Unix. This module has been a part of Perl-5 core since 1994.

Comment: If I ssh'ed into some minimalistic netbsd distribution embedded on some device - do you think it would have perl 5 and this module?