# Is there, in bash, a builtin command to get the absolute path of a relative file path?

Tags: bash, shell

I can use the external command `realpath` to get the absolute path of a file:

```
realpath tmp/toto
```

returns

```
/home/john/tmp/toto
```

Can I use a `bash` built-in to get the same effect?

Comment: Why do you want a `bash` builtin cmd for that ? Any specific reason that may enlighten us ?

Comment: @Cbhihe On non-Linux systems, there may not be a `realpath` command available at all.

Comment: On several non-Linux operating systems there is such a command, because they invented this stuff.  FreeBSD version 4.3 in 2001 was the origin of `realpath`, only in GNU coreutils since 2012, for example.  And even if there were not, there is no requirement for a _built-in_ command.  An alternative external command would surely suffice.  OpenBSD version 2.1 in 1997 was the origin of `readlink -f`, for example. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24342/5132

Comment: @JdeBP, if there was a built-in command (as in zsh), that would avoid spawning an OS process to just get absolute path.

Comment: Which is an argument that you could make for a text editor, and moreover _is not_ the reason that Kusalananda suggested.

Comment: `bash` will spawn a separate OS process for any subshell anyway, and unless your mythical `realpath` builtin were specially designed to take a variable name (like `export`, `local`, etc), you would need a command substitution (= subshell -> subprocess) in order to get its output into a variable.

Comment: My concern is mainly to avoid sub-shell and external command. I will stick with `realpath` for now, to keep it simple.

Comment: If one answer provided a solution for you, you should _accept_ that answer. See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash comes with a `realpath` loadable extension. Since bash-4.4 this should be installed by default¹, so you should be able to do:

```
BASH_LOADABLES_PATH=${BASH_LOADABLES_PATH:-/usr/local/lib/bash:/usr/lib/bash}
enable -f realpath realpath
realpath ..
help realpath
```

Once enabled, each loadable command becomes a "real" builtin with no additional fork/exec overhead, and with the ability to manipulate the bash environment (where offered, e.g. the `mypid` loadable)..

The `-f` option specifies the path to the loadable extension binary, if it's not in the expected place or your distro didn't set it correctly, you will need to set the variable `BASH_LOADABLES_PATH` to the directory containing extensions (or, use `-f` with the full path to the loadable). If it's set correctly, you won't need the first line above.

When writing portable scripts that prefer, but do not require such extensions, I will use a wrapper function anyway — along the lines of @Kusalananda's — so that it can fall back to an external (such as `readlink` or `realpath` from *coreutils*).

---

1. This extension is available since bash-2.05, but prior to bash-4.4 extensions were not compiled and installed by default, though it is [straightforward to do so](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashLoadableBuiltins) if you have a working build environment (C compiler etc.). Distributions may or may not include the extensions, sadly RHEL 8 (and hence CentOS 8) build bash-4.4 with the loadable extensions deliberately removed.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Any pointers for how to build these extensions? I'm running into trouble, despite the instructions in the wiki article you link to: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/582361/19157

Answer (score 5):

The `bash` shell does not have a built-in way to explicitly get an absolute path given a relative pathname.

In the `zsh` shell, one could do

```
pathname=../../home/kk/.zshenv
print -r -- $pathname:P
```

and get `/home/kk/.zshenv` back (note that it also resolves all symbolic links wherever possible is a similar way as `realpath()` would).

In `bash`, you could, for a pathname designating a non-directory and assuming you have search access to its parent directory, use

```bash
$ pathname=../../home/kk/.zshenv
$ ( OLDPWD=- CDPATH= cd -P -- "${pathname%/*}" && printf '%s/%s\n' "$PWD" "${pathname##*/}" )
/home/kk/.zshenv
```

That is, temporarily (in a sub-shell) `cd` to the directory holding the file, and then construct the absolute pathname using the value `$PWD` and the filename component of the pathname. The `-P` is needed to avoid `cd`'s special treatment of `..` components. It has the side effect of resolving symlinks components in the directory itself. If the file itself is a symlink however, it won't be resolved (that's a difference from `zsh`'s `:P` modifier).

We set `OLDPWD` to `-` to work around the fact that `cd -P -- -` does a `chdir($OLDPWD)` instead of `chdir("-")` (that trick works in `bash` but not all other `sh` implementations).

For a directory path it's easier:

```bash
$ pathname=../../home/kk
$ ( OLDPWD=- CDPATH= cd -P -- "$pathname" && pwd )
/home/kk
```

This could obviously be put into a shell function for convenience:

```bash
myrealpath () (
    if [[ -d $1 ]]; then
        OLDPWD=- CDPATH= cd -P -- "$1" && pwd
    else
        OLDPWD=- CDPATH= cd -P -- "${1%/*}" && printf '%s/%s\n' "$PWD" "${1##*/}"
    fi
)
```

(Note that this whole function is defined in a sub-shell to avoid changing the working directory for the calling shell.)

Testing this function:

```
$ myrealpath ../../home/kk
/home/kk
```

```
$ myrealpath ../../home/kk/.zshenv
/home/kk/.zshenv
```

Depending on the OS, using the function with no argument will return the absolute path of the current directory or give an error. In future versions of `bash`, that's likely to be an error on every system, as `cd ''` to fail will become a POSIX requirement.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer !

I'm aware of $pathname(:a) in zsh. That's exactly what I want to find equivalent in bash.

Using a sub-shell to get just an absolute path is a little overkill.

myrealpath is a nice try, but it does "cd", I still have to "cd" back to the original directory.

Comment: @Philippe The _point_ of the subshell is that you don't actually have to change back to the original directory.  The working directory is local to the subshell. Using `(cd somepath && some-command)` is a _very_ common way of running a command with a displaced working directory. It avoids having to `cd` back and forth in complicated ways.

Comment: Fair point. I think I'll use realpath for now, to keep it simple.

Comment: In `zsh`, that's be more like `$pathname:P`, `$pathname:a`, `$pathname:A`. See the manual (`info zsh Modifiers`) for the differences.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas As the question is geared towards `bash`, I have deleted the mentioning of `:A` and will instead only mention `:P`, and will not go down the path (!) of trying to explain more about that.

Comment: Since op already has zsh installed: `realpath(){ zsh -c "realpath $@"; }` laziest

Comment: @RakibFiha I'm noting that their motivation is performance (this was mentioned in a comment from them to a now deleted answer), which means that starting up a separate shell instance might not be the best option. Also, the `zsh` shell does not have a built in `realpath` utility, so your function would end up calling the external `realpath` utility anyway, if it's available.

Comment: Apologies, from the question, I thought `realpath` was zsh bultin or something like that. Just saw, OP mentioned its an external command

Comment: @RakibFiha No worries :-)  No, it's just a utility commonly found on Linux systems.

Comment: I meant `$pathname:P` as the `P` modifier applied to parameter expansion as opposed to a `(:P)` glob qualifier. The glob qualifier requires the file to exist.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Duh. Thanks.

Comment: `myrealpath` fails to produce the same results as `realpath` if the last path component is a symlink.  Also, if you just want an absolute path, I don't understand the need to use `cd`.  Just using `$PWD` should be sufficient (it's a different story if you use `cd -P`).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following, which have a high probability of working on non-Linux OSes (including AIX).  To compute an absolute path (i.e. a path starting at `/`):

```
abspath() {
  [[ $1 = /* ]] && printf "%s\n" "$1" || printf "%s\n" "$PWD/$1"
}
```

For a canonical path (i.e. one with all symlinks expanded):

```
canonical_path() {
  perl -mCwd -le ' print Cwd::abs_path $ARGV[0] ' -- "$1"
}
```

When testing against other possible solutions (including a call to `realpath`), you'll notice a significant difference depending on whether or not the last path component exists, and whether or not the last path component is a symlink.

Answer (score -1):

Some systems possess "realpath" command, e.g. Ubuntu. You can try `realpath ~/foo.txt` and it could give something like `/home/user/foo.txt`, then you can use `basedir` to cut off file name.

Comment: realpath is an external command, I'd like to have a bash builtin to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Oh, I am still sleepy - sorry for that, should read carefully.