# How to build loadable builtins for Bash

Tags: bash, make, c++, shell-builtin, plugin

As I recently learned, it's possible to dynamically load custom builtins into Bash (see [`enable` in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html), and [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/469259/134800)). However I'm not sure how to take advantage of this feature.

The linked question points to https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashLoadableBuiltins which provides some compilation instructions, but I'm not able to reproduce them (in Bash 5.0):

```
$ git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/bash.git
$ cd bash/
$ ./configure
$ make
$ exec ./bash
$ cd examples/loadables/
$ make
$ enable -f finfo finfo
bash: enable: cannot open shared object finfo: finfo: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

(Here's the [full output](https://pastebin.com/H9H6gYwE) just in case it's helpful)

Running `make` in the `examples/loadables` appears to be creating `.o` files, while (I think?) `enable` is looking for a `.so` file. Is there a step I've missed that would generate the appropriate artifacts? Is there an easier or more typical way to build custom builtins?

Comment: The wiki page links to a dead article, but it's preserved on archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20160303032434/http://cfajohnson.com/shell/articles/dynamically-loadable/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filename must be [an "absolute" path](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/general.c#n774) (in this context, that's just a path with a slash in it), or it will be looked up in `BASH_LOADABLES_PATH`, falling back to `dlopen(3)`'s search mechanism ([e.g., see the Linux manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)). It seems that, despite the comments in [`enable.def`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/enable.def#n314), these do not include the current directory (which is a good thing, IMO).

Just use a path:

```
bash-5.0$ enable -f print print
bash: enable: cannot open shared object print: print: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
bash-5.0$ enable -f ./print print
bash-5.0$ help print
print: print [-Rnprs] [-u unit] [-f format] [arguments]
    Display arguments.

    Output the arguments.  The -f option means to use the argument as a
    format string as would be supplied to printf(1).  The rest of the
    options are as in ksh.
```

Comment: Interesting, that makes sense! Any idea if this used to behave differently? Or maybe something about my machine has `dlopen` configured differently? It's odd that both the  Wooledge wiki page and the linked questions seemed to be able to use `enable` without making the filename "absolute" (seemingly without adjusting `BASH_LOADABLES_PATH`).

Comment: Going by [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/279069/229499), not in the past nine years. And in [the archived blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303032434/http://cfajohnson.com/shell/articles/dynamically-loadable/) linked the Wooledge wiki, you'll see it says `enable -f filename` but actually runs `enable ./strftime strftime` in the example. O.o

Comment: Thanks for the sleuthing :) this seems like such a useful feature, I wonder why it's gone mostly unused for so long (documentation is obviously a key reason...).